# Let $y$ be a lower bound of non-empty set $A$. Prove that $y = \inf A$ if the condition below is satisfied.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded from below.

1) Assume that $y$ is a lower bound for a nonempty bounded set $A$. Prove that $y = \inf A$ if and only if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is $a \in A$ such that $y \leq a < y + \epsilon$.

Since $y$ is a lower bound for $A$, we have that $y \leq a$ for every $a \in A$. By definition, $y = \inf A$ is the greatest lower bound, hence for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $y + \epsilon$ is greater than $y$. It follows that there exists $a \in A$ such that $a \leq y + \epsilon$.

Now let us assume $y \neq \inf A$. Then there is some number $z > y$, which is also a lower bound for $A$. Let $\epsilon = z- y$.

I am not sure how to finish this proof??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment for the forward direction:

The reason why $y+\epsilon > y$ is because of $\epsilon >0$. You still have to argue why there must exists such an $a \in A$ such that $y\leq a < y+\epsilon$. Try to answer the question of what if there is no such $a$, what can we say about $y+\epsilon$.

Now, for the backward direction:

$\epsilon = z-y>0$. Hence we can find $a \in A$ such that $y \leq a < z$, which contradicts that $z$ is a lower bound.